# Progress Dialog on Async Task

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I have created Three Classes, namely Mainactivity which is passing context to server class extending to `Asynctask`. There one class named setting, which call server class for updating data in server.

Code on Mainactivity for passing Context:

```
Server.setActivityContext(getApplicationContext());
```

Code for Sever Class:

```
public class Server extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {


static Context mycontext;

public static void setActivityContext(Context receivingcontext) {
    mycontext = receivingcontext;
}

Dialog dialog;

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    dialog = ProgressDialog.show(mycontext, "Updating ..", "Please wait......");
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
//Background task       
        return null;

}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    dialog.dismiss();
}
}
```

I am getting an error on `progressdialog` when calling this server class. Though context is passed, any fixes which you can suggest.

Error:

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main

    Process: jss.smartapp, PID: 22915 android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
```

Comment: post your logcat errors

Comment: in method setActivityContext (MainActivity.this) pass this as a context

Comment: Server.setActivityContext(MainActivity.this);//pass your activity context 
you have to pass activity context instead of application context..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use static methods. Use a proper constructor.

```
public class ServerTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private Context mycontext;

    public ServerTask(Context c) {
        this.mycontext = c;
    }
```

Call it with

```
new ServerTask(MainActivity.this).execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have method **setActivityContext** and  send back activity context, not application context

Answer (score 0):

You can create a constructor for passing the context like this

```
public class Server extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

private static final String TAG = "Server";
private Context mContext;

public Server(Context context){
    mContext = context;
}



Dialog dialog;

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    Log.d(TAG, "onPreExecute:called ");
    dialog = ProgressDialog.show(mContext, "Updating ..", "Please 
   wait......");
}

      @Override
      protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
      //Background task
       Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: called");
       return null;

       }

   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    Log.d(TAG, "onPostExecute: called");
    dialog.dismiss();
   }
}
```

and call this Server class like this

```
 new Server(MainActivity.class).execute();
```